# Reopen class in canJs

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-construct

As a class gets bigger and bigger it becomes harder to maintain. So I would love to divide some of my classes in multiple files. Defining the class in a file, something like:

```
var animal = can.Construct({
  someClassMethod: function() {...}
}, {
  somePrototypemethod: function() {...}
});
```

then later in a separate file I would love to *reopen* this class, and add new class methods/properties, and prototype methods/properties to it.

Is this possible in canJS? If no, what should be a possible workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add properties and methods to the prototype and the constructor. That's how JavaScript works.
So as long as you still have access to `animal` you can just do

```
animal.anotherClassMethod = function() {}
animal.prototype.anotherPrototypeMethod = function()
```

in another file. However, having class definitions get too big is usually a problem of them doing too much. If they get too big to be maintainable in one file (which would mean 2000+ lines of code)  there is definitely a better way to refactor besides just splitting them up. A downside of splitting it into separate files is definitely that it might be hard to know what functionality is where.